Ring homomorphisms between finite fields
I'm confused by this problem (A-52) from J.S. Milne - Field and Galois Theory

Let $E$ and $F$ be finite fields of the same characteristic. Prove or disprove these statements.
(a) There is a ring homomorphism of $F$ into $E$ iff $|E|$ is a power of $|F|$.
(b) There is an injective group homomorphism of the multiplicative group of $F$ into the multiplicative group of $E$ iff $|E|$ is a power of $|F|$.

According to the solution (a) is false (b) is true (the solution only says this).
Say $\textrm{char} \,E = \textrm{char} \,F = p$, $p$ prime. I agree that (b) is true as this follows from the fact that $p^a - 1 | p^b - 1$ iff $ a | b$. But why is (a) false? If such a ring Hom exists it induces an injective group Hom between the multiplicative groups, so by (b) $|E|$ is a power of $|F|$. On the other hand if $|E| = p^{c\times a}$ and $|F| = p^{a}$ then $E = \mathbb{F}_{p^{c\times a}} \supset \mathbb{F}_{p^{a}} = F$ and the field inclusion is such Hom.
What am I missing? (It may be something very dumb ...)

I agree. Part (a) looks correct to me, too. The kernel of a ring homomorphism is a proper ideal, and $F$ only has ${0}$. The homomorphism is thus injective, and turns $E$ into a f.d. vector space over $F$. In other words, we don't even need to require $E$ to be a field for (a) to hold. A finite ring will do!

Is it possible that Milne defines ring homomorphisms as just preserving addition and multiplication but not necessarily preserving $1$ ?  If so, then the map sending all of $E$ to $0$ is a ring homomorphism.

@AndreasBlass according to the first sentence of the book (https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/FT.pdf pag 7) "We require rings to have a 1, which entails that we require homomorphisms to preserve
it."  :D
